# Вставка данных в MsSQL базу данных 1Ски

Tags: sql-server, 1с

подскажите, с учетом "хитрой" структуры БД 1С возможно ли на ее уровне вставлять данные из другой БД ? Или тут только писать запросы на языке 1С и подгружать их с помощью текстовых файлов.
Просто нужно таблицу из одной БД дублировать, насколько это возможно, в 1Ску.

Answer (score 1):

Советую вам почитать информацию про объект метаданных "ВнешнийИсточникДанных". С его помощью вы можете подключать данные другой произвольной БД к интерфейсу 1С. И писать запросы, код и формы в концепциях 1С, работая напрямую с данными другой базы данных.

Можно прочесть информацию:

- [на сайте ИТС](https://its.1c.ru/db/v838doc/bookmark/dev/TI000000837) ([файл и описанием](https://files.fm/f/rs7eebjx));
- или же на других ресурсах, например на  [wiseadvice-it.ru](https://wiseadvice-it.ru/o-kompanii/blog/articles/rabota-s-vneshnimi-istochnikami-dannyh-v-1s-8-3/), [infostart.ru](https://infostart.ru/public/all/?st=t&sort=postsd&public-filter%5Bsearch%5D=%C2%ED%E5%F8%ED%E8%E5+%E8%F1%F2%EE%F7%ED%E8%EA%E8+%E4%E0%ED%ED%FB%F5) или [helpf.pro](https://helpf.pro/faq83/view/1223.html).

Comment: надо бы отзеркалить итс))

Comment: Файл с описанием: https://files.fm/f/rs7eebjx

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Не могли бы вы кратко описать идею, приведенную по указанным вами ссылкам. Ссылки имеют свойства «затухания». Думаю, многие будут вам благодарны!